# How to make derivative when function has double summation

Tags: summation, partial-derivative

I have a function which needs to be minimize, I know the basic idea of derivation and minimization but this expression killed me!

$min \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n(x_{ij}w_j-w_i)^2$
s.t. $\sum_{i=1}^n w_i=1$ where $w_i \ge 0, i=1,2,...,n$

I proceed like this

$\partial L/\partial w_i = \partial (\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n(x_{ij}w_j-w_i)^2)/\partial w_i  +\partial \lambda (\sum_{i=1}^n w_i- 1 )]/\partial w_i$

I know partial derivative of last part is

$\partial \lambda (\sum_{i=1}^n w_i- 1 )]/\partial w_i =n\lambda $

but derivative of first part is really hard for me and I could not move even a little 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Since you are using $i,j$ for the summation index, it might help to differentiate with respect to $w_k$. Then note: 
$$  \sum_j\sum_i (x_{ij}w_j-w_i)^2 = \sum_{i,j : i \neq k, j\neq k} (x_{ij}w_j-w_i)^2 + \sum_{j: j \neq k} (x_{kj}w_j-w_k)^2 + \sum_{i:i\neq k} (x_{ik}w_k-w_i)^2 + (x_{kk}w_k-w_k)^2 $$ Can you take the derivative now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Micheal](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/155065/michael), 
using your suggestion here is what I got.
$\frac{\partial\sum_j\sum_i (x_{ij}w_j-w_i)^2}{\partial w_k} =\frac{ \partial(\sum_{i,j : i \neq k, j\neq k} (x_{ij}w_j-w_i)^2 + \sum_{j: j \neq k} (x_{kj}w_j-w_k)^2 + \sum_{i:i\neq k} (x_{ik}w_k-w_i)^2 + (x_{kk}w_k-w_k)^2)}{\partial w_k}$

$= 0 -2 \sum_{j:j\neq k}(x_{kj}w_j-w_k)+0-2(x_{kk}w_j-w_k)$

$= -2 \sum_{j}(x_{kj}w_j-w_k)$

and from other way I got this solution

$ \frac {\partial \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n(x_{ij}w_j-w_i)^2}{\partial w_i} = \frac { \sum_{j=1}^n \partial\sum_{i=1}^n(x_{ij}w_j-w_i)^2}{\partial w_i}$

$= -2 \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n(x_{ij}w_j-w_i)$

I got two different result, did i make any mistake?
in previous result, where my $w_i$ gone or can i simply change subsrcipt k to i? or later one has issue?

Answer (score 1):

> Note that in the expression
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n(x_{ij}w_j-w_i)^2
> \end{align*}
>   the variables $i$ and $j$ are *[bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables)* indexvariables, which are visible only within the range of the summation symbol.

This invalidates your second approach, since the variable which is subject to differentiation must not be  indexed by $i$ or $j$. Now the first approach in some detail.

> Let $1\leq k \leq n$. We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{\partial}{\partial w_k}&\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n(x_{ij}w_j-w_i)^2\\
> &=\frac{\partial}{\partial w_k}\sum_{{j=1}\atop{j\neq k}}^n\sum_{{i=1}\atop{i\neq k}}^n(x_{ij}w_j-w_i)^2
> +\frac{\partial}{\partial w_k}(x_{kk}w_k-w_k)^2\\
> &\qquad+\frac{\partial}{\partial w_k}\sum_{{i=1}\atop{i\neq k}}^n(x_{ik}w_k-w_i)^2
> +\frac{\partial}{\partial w_k}\sum_{{j=1}\atop{j\neq k}}^n(x_{kj}w_j-w_k)^2\\
> &=0+(x_{kk}-1)^2\frac{\partial}{\partial w_k}w_k^2\\
> &\qquad+\frac{\partial}{\partial w_k}\sum_{{i=1}\atop{i\neq k}}^n(x_{ik}w_k-w_i)^2
> +\frac{\partial}{\partial w_k}\sum_{{j=1}\atop{j\neq k}}^n(x_{kj}w_j-w_k)^2\\
> &=2w_k(x_{kk}-1)^2+2\sum_{{i=1}\atop{i\neq k}}^n(x_{ik}w_k-w_i)(x_{ik})+
> 2\sum_{{j=1}\atop{j\neq k}}^n(x_{kj}w_j-w_k)(-1)\\
> &=2w_k(x_{kk}-1)^2+2w_k\sum_{{i=1}\atop{i\neq k}}^nx_{ik}^2-2\sum_{{i=1}\atop{i\neq k}}^nx_{ik}w_i-
> 2\sum_{{j=1}\atop{j\neq k}}^nx_{kj}w_j+2(n-1)w_k\\
> &=2w_k(x_{kk}-1)^2+2w_k\sum_{{i=1}\atop{i\neq k}}^nx_{ik}^2-2\sum_{{i=1}\atop{i\neq k}}^n(x_{ik}+x_{ki})w_i+2(n-1)w_k\\
> &=2w_k(x_{kk}^2-2x_{kk}+n)+2w_k\sum_{{i=1}\atop{i\neq k}}^nx_{ik}^2-2\sum_{{i=1}\atop{i\neq k}}^n(x_{ik}+x_{ki})w_i\\
> &=2w_kn+2w_k\sum_{{i=1}}^nx_{ik}^2-2\sum_{{i=1}}^n(x_{ik}+x_{ki})w_i\\
> \end{align*}

Comment: @Sudas: You're welcome! Good to see the answer is helpful.